# Making a button appear in Android when a condition is fulfilled

Tags: android, button

As the title says I'd like to know the best method for generating a button upon some condition being fulfilled in my code. In this case, I'd like clicking on a particular imageView "s02" to make a button appear in my activity.

I know that you can make AlertDialogs appear using code like this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // code code code code code  }
                });
```

I tried substituting Button for AlertDialog on the first line but I couldn't use Builder on Button.

Also, should I create the button in a separate section of code then simply make it appear when the condition is set, or should I put the button's functionality in the code creating the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your button in the xml layout and just making it appear when needed is the easiest route.  If that isn't good enough, you can create a Button via new Button(Context), set all the parameters you need, then add it to the parent layout.